# Abrir varias ventana de chrome y colocar datos variables con selenium en python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Tengo un script en python para hacer unas pruebas de un portal con Selenium. En el scrpit le digo la cantidad de navegadores al mismo tiempo (variable `cant = 3)` y, la cantidad de veces que quiero que me repita ese proceso (variable `rpt = 2`). En el script tengo que el navegador se cierre después de 60min .

Este es el cógido "*mi script*:

```
cant = 3
rpt = 2

opts1 = Options()
opts1.add_argument('--user-agent=%s'% useragent)
opts1.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s'% proxy)
opts1.add_argument('--headless')
opts1.add_argument('--start-maximized')
browser1 = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts1)
browser1.execute_script("window.location.replace(arguments[0])", "http://midominio.com")
time.sleep(10)
with open('contraseñas.txt') as f:
    credentials = [x.strip().split(':', 1) for x in f]
for username, password in credentials:
    browser1.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="usuario"] """).send_keys(usuario)
    time.sleep(2)
    browser1.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="contrsena"] """).send_keys(contrasena)
    submit = browser1.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="iniciar"] """)
    submit.click()
    time.sleep(60)
    browser1.quit()
```

El punto está que no he logrado hacerlo que funcione.

He intentado hacerlo así:

```
cant = 3
i = 1
while i <= rpt:
    #Por cada elemento en driver(por cada browser) que haga lo siguiente (muchos navegadore haciendo lo mismo)

    for elem in range(cant):
    opts[i] = Options()
        opts[i].add_argument('--user-agent=%s'% useragent)
        opts[i].add_argument('--proxy-server=%s'% proxy)
        #opts[i].add_argument('--headless')
    opts[i].add_argument('--start-maximized')
        browser[i] = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts[i])
        browser[i].execute_script("window.location.replace(arguments[0])", ""http://midominio.com")
        time.sleep(30)
    
    with open('contraseñas.txt') as f:
            credentials = [x.strip().split(':', 1) for x in f]
    for username, password in credentials:
            browser1.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="usuario"] """).send_keys(usuario)
            time.sleep(2)
        browser1.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="contrsena"] """).send_keys(contrasena)
        submit = browser1.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="iniciar"] """)
        submit.click()
        time.sleep(60)
        browser1.quit()
```

El objetivo en este ejemplo es: abrir 3 ventanas de chrome, que ingrese los datos en cada una ( y de ser posible que se ejecuten simultáneamente), y que luego de 60min la cierre y que esto se repita 2 veces.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda! Pueden sugerir mejoras en código.

Nota: Principiante en python (menos de 1 semana)